# 0 ->1 Soft Transition node : Steepness is clamped along a curve

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics

I often need a soft 0 -> 1  transition function. So I made it using this mathematical fuction :

(a) parameter determines the speed of the transition ( its steepness )
(b) parameter determines where the transition occures.

[image: soft transition math fuction]

Here it is turned into a node :

[image: soft transition node group]

Then I tried to use it to compute the radius of a curve to make it softly transition between 0 & 1 :

[image: sotf transition on a curve radius]

Strangely, it is as if the "Transition Speed" parameter was clamped. All I get is a very slow transition. And I couldn't debug it :
[image: curve with tto slow a transiyion]

If I increase the "Transition Speed" parameter, it stops having any effect above 9.

In fact it is a very useful node ( and it could be native ) ... so solving this would be great.

File :

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a default *Bezier Curve* which has only 2 control points. Check it in *Edit* mode. Since the *x shift* is 0.5 (=center of the curve), the first point gets a radius of `0.0` and the end point gets a radius of `1.0`. It works as designed! :-)

I guess you expect something like the following. For this you need more control points (=more *x* values):

[image]

Try a *Resample Curve* node with *Count* 50. To see the effect more clearly, you can also add a *Map Range* node to scale the 0.0-1.0 range to a wider range. (A curve with a radius of 0.0 is not visible).

Comment: Thanks Blunder !  Now my question seems ridiculous.   ... the radius is evaluated on control points and only there ...